# Running Python script using shell script redirecting python output

Tags: shell-script, python, output

I am running my python script using a shell script `run.sh` to restart it if crashes :

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMAND='nohup python3 -u test.py run >> py.log &'
LOGFILE=restart.txt

writelog() {
  now=`date`
  echo "$now $*" >> $LOGFILE
}

writelog "Starting"
while true ; do
  $COMMAND
  writelog "Exited with status $?"
  writelog "Restarting"
done
```

I'm running

```
nohup sh -u run.sh > output&
```

**The problem is python would only stream the first output(print()) to py.log**. How can I get out the output streamed instantly. I have also tried `COMMAND=./test.py run >> py.log &` . I would appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the `&` at the end of the `COMMAND`? That causes the command to background

Comment: That doesn't seem to work at all. The `>>` in the string is not understood as a redirection,  your python script must be getting `>>` and `py.log` as parameters.

Comment: whether i  use `&` or not it doesn't work @iruvar

Comment: @xenoid it redirect the output to `py.log` . but only the first line. Next outputs are not streamed .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the module `redirect_stdout` to redirect output to a file and then using `sys.stdout.flush()` after each `print()` and for the shell script `COMMAND='./test.py run'`. Now it's streaming the output in realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Your shell script is passing the string `'run >> py.log &'` to your `test.py` script, which is probably causing it not to run correctly.

You need to change you script slightly:

```
#!/bin/sh

COMMAND='nohup python3 -u test.py run'
LOGFILE=restart.txt

writelog() {
  now=`date`
  echo "$now $*" >> $LOGFILE
}

writelog "Starting"
while true ; do
  $COMMAND >> py.log &
  writelog "Exited with status $?"
  writelog "Restarting"
done
```

Now your `$COMMAND` will run in the background and append it's output to `py.log`.

The reason your original script does not work is because the shell variables are expanded after output redirections are set, so the `>>` and `&` were no longer recognized as part of the shell command and passed as the argument string to your Python script.  You can reference `LESS='+/SIMPLE COMMAND EXPANSION' man bash` for steps used in processing commands.

Comment: The line `$COMMAND >> py.log &` causes the python process to run in the background and so the script will immediately proceed to `writelog "Exited with status $?"`, probably before the python process has exited. This is not the intended behavior I think.